# select attribute mysql

Tags: filter, product, attributes, mysql, php

I have there mysql table:

```
**product (id,name)**
1  Samsung
2  Toshiba
3  Sony

**attribute (id,name,parentid)**
1 Size 0
2 19" 1
3 17" 1
4 15" 1
5 Color 0
6 White 5
7 Black 5
8 Price 0
9 <$100 8
10 $100-$300 8
11 >$300 8

**attribute2product (id,productid,attributeid)**
1 1 2
2 1 6
3 2 2
4 2 7
5 3 3
6 3 7
7 1 9
8 2 9
9 3 10
```

And listed them like:

```
**Size**
-- 19" (2)
-- 17" (1)
-- 15" (0)

**Color**
-- White (1)
-- Black (2)

**Price**
-- <$100 (1)
-- $100-$300 (1)
-- >$300 (1)
```

Please help me the mysql query to list the attribute name and count the number product that this attribute have. EG: When select Size 19" (attribute.id 2)

```
**Size**
-- 19"

**Color**
-- White (1)
-- Black (1)

**Price**
-- <$100 (1)
-- $100-$300 (1)
```

This will query to attribute2product >> select the productid >> next query to select other attribute of that productid and display the attribute name, number of prod that attribute name now have... (Like Magento)

Thanks,

Comment: Could you post the code for listing them? It might help.

Comment: @Chris Chua: I want to learn the mysql query (select, join, EAV table..) listing like Magento's products attribute filter.

Comment: Shouldn't `White` and `Black` have the parent id `5`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified the query. This should be what you based on your updates:

```
SELECT attribute.name AS attributename, COUNT(*) AS numofproducts FROM product 
  INNER JOIN attribute2product ON  attribute2product.productid = product.id
  INNER JOIN attribute ON attribute.id = attribute2product.attributeid
  WHERE product.id IN 
    (
     SELECT p.id FROM product AS p
     INNER JOIN attribute2product AS a2p ON a2p.productid = p.id
     WHERE a2p.attributeid = 2
    )
  GROUP BY attribute.id, attribute.name;
```

Based on your above data I got:

```
  attributename   numofproducts
       19"              2
      White             1
      Black             1
      <$100             2
```

For multiple attributes ([based a more knowledgeable expert Quassnoi's blog article](http://explainextended.com/2010/04/02/multiple-attributes-in-a-eav-table-group-by-vs-not-exists/)) :
<sub>I've removed product table since it's not needed here</sub>

```
SELECT attribute.name AS attributename, COUNT(*) AS numofproducts
FROM attribute2product
  INNER JOIN attribute ON attribute.id = attribute2product.attributeid
  WHERE attribute2product.productid IN (
      SELECT o.productid
      FROM (
        SELECT productid 
        FROM (
          SELECT 2 AS att
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 6 AS att
          ) v
        JOIN attribute2product ON attributeid >= att AND attributeid <= att
        ) o
      GROUP BY o.productid
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
      )
  GROUP BY attribute.id, attribute.name
```

`2`, `6` refer to `19"` and `White`, respectively. `COUNT(*) = 2` is to match 2 attributes. More attributes can be added by appending the following to nested derived table:

```
          UNION ALL
          SELECT <attributeid> AS att
```

As expected the result from the query:

```
  attributename   numofproducts
       19"              1
      White             1
      <$100             1
```

Comment: That first inner join should be on `attribute2product.productid = product.id`

Comment: Cannot filter when select attribute with your query, Chris Chua. It will display the name of attribute we selected. Anyway, i've edited the Question and try to explain to you. Please help!

Comment: I missed out an `ON` in my code, just added it in. It should return both the name of the attribute selected as well as the number of products with that attribute. Could you post your result here if you are still having problems?

Comment: My result shows:

**Size**
-- 19" (2)

**Color**
-- 19" (2)

**Price**
-- 19" (2)

Comment: I've modified my answer based on your new information. Please take a look. :)

Comment: Chris, the 19" has 2 products. And with 19" products, have two Color  attribute (white: 1 and black: 1 ) and two Price (<$100: 1 product, $100-$300 have 1 product)

When we filter by the 19" attribute, it will select and count the number of products, and the other attributes 2 remain products now have.

With your exp, please help me.
Thank Chris!

Comment: Apologies, I made another typo again! Trey mentioned it and I made the same mistake haha. There you go. :)

Comment: Thanks Chris, it works perfect. But.. when i'm select multi attribute, such as: 19" and White, the display is incorrect.

Magento system allows us filter by multi attribute. Take a look at _http://demo.magentocommerce.com/electronics/digital-cameras

Please ..help me Chris!